# Spring: How to inject a String bean to the constructor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a class `Config`:

**Config.java**

```
public class Config {
    private final String p = "Prop";

    @Bean
    public String getP(){return p;}
}
```

How do I inject this to some constructor, ie:

```
public class SomeC {
    private String p;

    public SomeC(String p) {
        this. p = p;
    }
}
```

I want this String `p` to have injected value from Config. Is that possible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You will have to name the bean, and then use the `@Qualifier` annotation when autowiring referencing that name.

Example:

**Config.java**

```
public class Config {
    private final String p = "Prop";

    @Bean(name="p")
    public String getP(){return p;}
}
```

**SomeC.java**

```
public class SomeC {
    private String p;

    @Autowired
    public SomeC(@Qualifier("p") String p) {
        this. p = p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use a something like @Qualifier(Config.BEAN_NAME)? If you specify the BEAN_NAME there?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. I have done that before in an application where I needed to reference the bean name in multiple places.

Comment: If you name your bean method() like this,  public String p(){return p;} , then @Qualifier is NOT required. It is very simple.

Comment: @SundararajGovindasamy the qualifier would still be required, but the `name` would not be required on the `@Bean`.

Comment: You have only one bean with the name 'p', then why you need @Qualifer?

Comment: @SundararajGovindasamy, you may be correct. Since String is a pretty generic object, I would always use a `@Qualifier` to be less ambiguous.

Comment: ambiguous with what?

Comment: @SundararajGovindasamy The reason you have to specify Qualifier is that reflection doesn't generally have access to parameter names, so Spring can't match "String p" with getP() since the compiler threw away the fact that the string's name was "p"

Comment: @BillK, Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@Autowired` either like this:

```
@Autowired
public SomeC(String p){
  this.p = p;
}
```

or like this:

```
public class SomeC {

  @Autowired
  private String p;

}
```

I prefer the second approach, but this makes the classes more difficult to test, since the dependencies are not visible from the outside, so use with caution.

Comment: And what if you have multiple String beans in your app? How does it know which one to autowire then?

Comment: by name, or by qualifier. I preffer by name

Comment: Ideally, you won't use String beans at all - you'd extract those to a properties file (especially in Spring context) and access that by using `@Value` on the String field

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one `String`-type bean, you can it without any changes. Injection by type is usable.

```java
@Configuration
public class Config {
    private final String p = "Prop";

    @Bean
    public String getP() {
        return p;
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class SomeC {

    private String p;

    public SomeC(String p) {
        this.p = p;
    }
}
```

If there are multiple `String`-type beans, you can inject by name.

```java
@Configuration
public class Config {
    private final String p = "Prop";
    private final String q = "AnotherProp";

    @Bean
    public String getP() {
        return p;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public String getQ() {
        return q;
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class SomeC {

    @Resource(name = "getP")
    private String p;
```

Default bean name is method name `getP`.
You can rename by `@Bean("customName")` annotation.

Note:

- [1.9.4. Fine-tuning Annotation-based Autowiring with Qualifiers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.3/reference/html/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)

> if you intend to express annotation-driven injection by name, do not primarily use `@Autowired` (snip). Instead, use the JSR-250 `@Resource` annotation

> `@Resource` is supported only for fields and bean property setter methods with a single argument.

Injection by qualifier is available for constructor injection.

```java
@Configuration
public class Config {
    private final String p = "Prop";
    private final String q = "AnotherProp";

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("p")
    public String getP() {
        return p;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("q")
    public String getQ() {
        return q;
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class SomeC {

    private String p;

    public SomeC(@Qualifier("p") String p) {
        this.p = p;
    }
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41570973/4506703) is a fallback behavior. Name and qualifier are different one.

- [1.9.4. Fine-tuning Annotation-based Autowiring with Qualifiers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.3/reference/html/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)

> For a fallback match, the bean name is considered a default qualifier value.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SomeC {
  private String p;

  public SomeC(@Value("prop") String p) {
    this. p = p;
  }
}
```