# Beans not injected into jUnit test

Tags: java, spring

I have a problem with proper Spring Beans configuration. My whole app works properly with Spring and I wanted to add jUnit tests. Unfortunately, beans are not injected properly. 
I have two directories inside same module. 
My whole app is inside:

/src/main/java/main/

which works correctly and I added RestTest.java and BeanTestConfiguration.java
inside:

/src/test/java/main/

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(Spring.Runner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=BeanTestConfiguration.class)
class RestTest {

    @Autowired
    public String testString;


    @Test
    public void send() {
        System.out.println(testString);
        Assert.assertNotNull(testString);
    }
}
```

And config BeanTestConfiguration

```
@Configuration
public class BeanTestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public String testString() { return new String("Hello"); }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run test on send method System out prints null, and Assert throws fail. 
I added Spring Application Context to Project Structure inside IntelliJ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring: How to inject a String bean to the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570821/spring-how-to-inject-a-string-bean-to-the-constructor)

Comment: It's completely different problem. Solution there is literally my code

Comment: I took your code inside a new project SpringBoot and everything worked like a charm. I just had to put the RestTest class and the method send public. Could you add your stacktrace?

Answer (score 2):

Thank You all for help. I found out I had problem with the imports. My @Test annotation was from jUnit 5, whereas I had SpringRunner inside annotation which was from jUnit 4, as a result Spring wasn't working correctly and beans weren't injected.

One more time I want to thank You all.

Answer (score 0):

As your test class and method is package private I assume you are using jUnit 5.
In jUnit 5 instead of `@RunWith` you should use the [`@ExtendWith`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions) annotation. In particular the [SpringExtension](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit/jupiter/SpringExtension.html)

> By annotating test classes with @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class), developers can implement standard JUnit Jupiter based unit and integration tests and simultaneously reap the benefits of the TestContext framework such as support for loading application contexts, dependency injection of test instances, transactional test method execution, and so on.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-junit-jupiter-extension

E.g.

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=BeanTestConfiguration.class)
class RestTest {

    @Autowired
    public String testString;


    @Test
    void send() {
        System.out.println(testString);
        Assert.assertNotNull(testString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry It was my typo, test method was public. Test is executed correctly, but  bean is not injected.