# Error in creating bean: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

**Error obtained while runtime of the code**

```
EVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'xx' defined in file [/home/xx/sts_ws4/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mis-compliance/WEB-INF/classes/com/moveinsync/compliance/services/xx.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1267)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1124)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:499)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:172)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5085)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5397)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1400)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724)
    ... 28 more

Oct 05, 2018 9:15:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [dispatcher] in web application [/mis-compliance] threw load() exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1267)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1124)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:499)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:172)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5085)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5397)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1400)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Service class: Here I have annotted this class as well as mentioned this 
 package in @componentscan annotation**

```
@Service
public class EHSCheckedVehiclesGetter implements Callable<List<VehicleEHSDTO>> {

  private VehicleEHSRepository vrepo;

  private String buid;

  public EHSCheckedVehiclesGetter() {

  }
  public EHSCheckedVehiclesGetter(VehicleEHSRepository vrepo, String buid) {
    Assert.notNull(vrepo, "VehicleEHSInfoRepository cannot be null");
    Assert.notNull(buid, "Business Unit Id cannot be null");
    this.vrepo = vrepo;
    this.buid = buid;
  }

  @Override
  public List<VehicleEHSDTO> call() throws Exception {
    List<PVehicleEHSChecklistStatus> pVehicleEHSInfos = vrepo.findByBuid(buid);
    List<VehicleEHSDTO> vehicleEHSInfoDTOs = VehicleUtils.convert(pVehicleEHSInfos);
    return vehicleEHSInfoDTOs;
  }
```

**Repository class: this is the interface for repository and the I have given this package in @EnableJpaRepositories annotation in as base packages**

```
public interface VehicleEHSRepository extends JpaRepository<PVehicleEHSChecklistStatus, PVehicleEHSChecklistStatusId>,
    MISRevisionRepository<PVehicleEHSChecklistStatus, PVehicleEHSChecklistStatusId, Integer> {

  @Query("from PVehicleEHSChecklistStatus where id.businessUnitId = ?1")
  List<PVehicleEHSChecklistStatus> findByBuid(String buid);

  @Query("from PVehicleEHSChecklistStatus where id.vehicleId = ?1")
  List<PVehicleEHSChecklistStatus> findByVehicleId(String vehicleId);
```

Can this be related to something other than this, because I'm trying to update my tech stack in project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are injecting a String in the constructor:`public EHSCheckedVehiclesGetter(VehicleEHSRepository vrepo, String buid){ this.buid = buid }`
The error is for injecting this String while initializing EHSCheckedVehiclesGetter
You can do something like this:
[Spring: How to inject a String bean to the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570821/spring-how-to-inject-a-string-bean-to-the-constructor)

Comment: Is there a reason you are injecting buid? EHSCheckedVehiclesGetter is a Spring bean and not a POJO

Comment: No i can try new thing, any suggestion

Comment: You can send buid to the call() method as an argument every time you need to. Places where you need the EHSCheckedVehiclesGetter service you won't be doing a new but instead @Autowire it and then access its methods.

Comment: Thanks, will try that. Thanks again.